# Android ImageView with nine patch background are rotated at 180 degree

Tags: android, imageview, nine-patch

All ok, but images are rotated at 180 degree.
Without nine patch background all ok.

Maybe my nine patch wrong?

How to prevent this rotation?

[Rotation sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56zHM.png)

[My nine patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CItAu.png)

There is my view:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_tv_channel_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/layout_apps_app_item_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/activity_main_nav_selector"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/blank_channel_logo" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout_apps_app_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingEnd="3dp"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/fontcolor"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it may sound stuped, but are you sure that `blank_channel_logo` is not rotated itself?

Comment: No. In the adapter I set another image to the imageview.
And without 9-patch background all ok.

Comment: then it themes like a bug in OS, or so... Have you tried different devices?